# How to set up RAID 1?

Tags: raid, disk, disk-management

How to set up RAID 1 (software, hardware or fake) on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop?

Comment: Why the down-votes? This looks like a decent question & I didn't find any exact dupes. +1 from me.

Comment: @TomBrossman The word “implement” in the title evoked a programming question, at least to me. I changed the title.

Answer (score 7):

RAID 1 is mirroring; where data is duplicated on two different drives using either a hardware RAID controller or software (via the operating system). If either drive fails, the other continues to function as a single drive until the failed drive is replaced.

First thing that needs to be done is to install mdadm.  To do so

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
apt-get install mdadm
```

Or use USC

[image]

Once that is done,

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
mdadm
```

`--create` creates a new RAID device

and follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install on a boot volume with RAID, you can't use the desktop install CD.  You need to use the "alternate install" CD:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Inside that installer you'll have the options to create a RAID (MD) device and/or use LVM.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installing_on_external_or_RAID_hard_disks