# Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda while installing Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 from USB on an old computer. 
I have two 4TB drives I want to run in RAID 1, I also have two other drives running win 7.

The motherboard is Gigabyte GA-X48-DQ6, (it is without EFI)

When I partition the drives according to this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html.en 
I'm not able to set the bootable flag on.

Following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KiWxMDKu94, I get an error saying "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda".

My 4TB drives are recognized as sda and sdc. And I allocate 15GB as swap and the rest as Ext4, with/as a mount point.

Can anyone help with this issue?

**EDIT:**
The problem was related to the drive size. GRUB install is problematic on drives > 2TB. Solution was to install OS on another drive and then set up raid following this solution: [How can I create a RAID array with >2TB disks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350266/how-can-i-create-a-raid-array-with-2tb-disks)

Comment: You might want to check your release - there was no Ubuntu release in 2018.August (releases are yy.mm format).  Of the two Ubuntu releases this year, 1 is *currently* off-topic, 1 is supported...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda" when installing GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If (the answers to) the linked question doesn’t help please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` after you choose the boot menu option “Try Ubuntu”. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidFoerster. I have no "Try Ubuntu" option in the boot menu. Note that I am using the Ubuntu Server alternate installer.

Comment: In that case please try to find another way to get Linux command-line access e. g. via the installation image of Ubuntu Desktop or some other Linux distro. It will be difficult to proceed without this info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a RAID array with >2TB disks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350266/how-can-i-create-a-raid-array-with-2tb-disks)

Comment: For BIOS boot grub on gpt drives grub requires a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag or code ef02 if using gdisk. But bios_grub must be with in first 2TiB of drive.