# Installing Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 using Raid 1, Need a step by step guide

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, raid

Lately, I am trying to build a server that uses Ubuntu Server 12.04.3(64bit) . I am facing problem while wanting to install under a software RAID(RAID 1). My Server spec are as below:

Proccesor: Intel i5-4670
Motherboard： Asus H87M-E V1
RAM: 2X 4GB 1600mhz
Hardisk: 2x 2TB WD Red Cavier

I already tried either Software RAID and Hardware RAID. Software RAID can't install bootloader and Hardware RAID won't let me partition.
This is my first time directly doing RAID 1 on the OS HDD. Kind of Newbie here. Anyone who had this experience please share. Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question has already been asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/155872/how-to-implement-raid-1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Live-CD open ubuntu terminal and follow following steps.

> sudo su

Then install mdadm

> apt-get install mdadm

Using mdadm command to create raid1

> mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2
>   /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1

Don't forget change /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdc1 to match with your drive. And using the same command match all your partitions.

Then save raid configuration by using.

> mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

That's it.

*PS. Sometime I have to download installation from USA source because it won't allow me config raid*